# Prevent toolbar from dropping down when moving mouse to the top while using full-screen applications in Mac OS

Tags: google-chrome, mac, chrome-remote-desktop

My ask is pretty simple; I'm using chrome remote desktop on a Mac, and in the remote computer if I move my mouse to the top of the screen to click a browser tab, it will trigger the Mac toolbar to dropdown and cover everything, thereby stealing my click. Therefore I want to **prevent the toolbar from appearing at all while using full-screen applications.**

Seems like a pretty common use case with tons of users having the same issue right? Well you might be surprised, this is not a standard feature supported by Apple, who for some inane reason decided that the only two options shall be "always show" and "show only when cursor goes to top". "Always show" doesn't even work on their newer Macbook Pros with the notch and has no effect (moreover, even if it did work, not only would it reduce screen space, but also there would still be an extra gray bar below the toolbar which pops up, which *still* covers up all the tabs and steals your click).

There is no "always hide" option for the toolbar. And by the way, Mac is the only OS who does this and neither Linux or Windows has this issue.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an up-to-date Mac system version (Sonoma) on the remote Mac (or the host), try the different choices for

> System Settings>Control Center>Menu Bar Only (at the very bottom, for
> me)>Automatically hide and show the menu bar

If you're using an older Mac system version, try [this](https://community.graphisoft.com/t5/Installation-update/Mac-full-screen-hides-menu-bar-unless-mouse-over/td-p/401003).

Actual Mac OS X (not macOS) is pretty ancient nowadays, so if you're really working with that, try looking for "menu bar" instead of "toolbar". Let me know the version number (macOS 14.4 is recent, 10.15.7 would be actual Mac OS X) and I'll try to look further.

Comment: Thank you for the response and I've corrected my question title to Mac OS (not X). However, the thing you suggested is precisely what I explained is not working, and Google searches are riddled with this suggestion which is not helpful to us. It only allows you to "always show" or "sometimes show". The 2nd paragraph explains why "always show" doesn't work, and even if it did work, it would be better to have an "always hide" option.

Comment: Sonoma appears to have the option in the long list of Control Center options in System Settings (Automatically hide and show the menu bar), and that option includes 4 choices: "Always",
"On Desktop Only",  "In Full Screen Only", and "Never". Is upgrading to Sonoma an option? I am using it with fewer problems than I had with Ventura. I know that using older hardware and software can be troublesome for Apple's concept of backwards compatibility, which is nearly non-existent. Different display resolutions in System Settings>Displays? Hopefully the Show all resolutions toggle is available.

Comment: I'm already on Sonoma. Yes, I see there are 4 options, but if you think about it none of them amount to "always hide", which is very unfortunate because based on the wording it's very easy for LLMs and search engines to be tricked into thinking that this is definitely the solution. But if you examine the issue more closely, the behavior being toggled is called "automatically show and hide menu bar". So, if it is true, then it will auto show/hide, and if it is false, it will always show. In any given subset in the dropdown it will have to have one of those two states. There is no always hide.

Comment: It seems logical to me that Apple would not provide a setting under which the menu bar is always hidden, but I can choose for it to remain above the top window for any app's full screen window, so that it doesn't appear as long as I don't let the cursor stray above that border. I can understand your frustration now. I didn't realize that seeing the menu bar at all while you're in Chrome Remote Desktop is not acceptable, I just thought you wanted uninterrupted access to the browser tabs. Maybe someday, but for now Apple considers the menu bar indispensable.